# Remove de-focus region on image by opencv

Tags: opencv, image-processing, focus, feature-detection

I have an image and 2 regions (focus region and de-focus region). I use Open CV, I want to detect near region. 
I apply watershed in OpenCV or Canny detector to detect the object. But the object includes near and far region.

So, I need an idea or help from anyone help me apply OpenCV to detect near region image.

Code for show image, that I attached.

```
private Mat CalculateMapStrength(Mat inputMat){
    Imgproc.cvtColor(inputMat,inputMat, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);
    //Compute dx and dy derivatives
    Mat dx = new Mat();
    Mat dy = new Mat();
    Imgproc.Sobel(inputMat, dx, CV_32F, 1, 0);
    Imgproc.Sobel(inputMat, dy, CV_32F, 0, 1);
    Core.convertScaleAbs(dx,dx);
    Core.convertScaleAbs(dy,dy);
    Mat outputMat = new Mat();
    Core.addWeighted(dx,0.5,dy,0.5,0,outputMat);
    return outputMat;
}
```

Beside, I get Image segmentation by watershed algorithm in OpenCV. Can I compile 2 result for detect object? How to compile that?

```
public Mat steptowatershed(Mat img)
{
    Mat threeChannel = new Mat();
    Imgproc.cvtColor(img, threeChannel, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    Imgproc.threshold(threeChannel, threeChannel, 100, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);
    Mat fg = new Mat(img.size(),CvType.CV_8U);
    Imgproc.erode(threeChannel,fg,new Mat());
    Mat bg = new Mat(img.size(),CvType.CV_8U);
    Imgproc.dilate(threeChannel,bg,new Mat());
    Imgproc.threshold(bg,bg,1, 128,Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV);
    Mat markers = new Mat(img.size(),CvType.CV_8U, new Scalar(0));
    Core.add(fg, bg, markers);
    Mat result1=new Mat();
    WatershedSegmenter segmenter = new WatershedSegmenter();
    segmenter.setMarkers(markers);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(img, img, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2RGB);
    result1 = segmenter.process(img);
    return result1;
}

public class WatershedSegmenter
{
    public Mat markers=new Mat();
    public void setMarkers(Mat markerImage)
    {
        markerImage.convertTo(markers, CvType.CV_32SC1);
    }
    public Mat process(Mat image)
    {
        Imgproc.watershed(image,markers);
        markers.convertTo(markers,CvType.CV_8U);
        return markers;
    }
}
```

[image: Image detected region includes far-focus regions] 
[image: applied WaterShed]

Comment: Please post your code to help others help you. Also see: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I just update function for show image, that I attacked. Now, I can detect Edge by Canny Detect function by OpenCV. But, I don't know, how to remove far-region in this image.

Comment: I use threshold for remove de-focus object. But I can't combine 2 results for getting focus region of the image. Anybody can help me? Thanks.